# Set a "case" to "confirmed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure if my solution ist the best way to solve this:

My users are able to create "cases". After a period of time, there should be an action to turn the cases they create earlier to confirmed.

I tried to solve that with "on: :member" route like this:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :cases do
    post 'confirm', on: :member
  end
```

Now I want to create an action in cases_controller, where I set a case form 'confirmed_at' to 'time.now'. But how can I do that?

Here is my **schema.rb** for cases

```
create_table "cases", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "gender"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.string "place_of_residence"
    t.string "diagnosis"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_cases_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: are you expecting the confirmation to happen automatically without user interaction or through user interaction?

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention that: Though user interaction.

Comment: `confirmed_at` should be set to `Time.now` based on user interaction ? If so then you would have to create another action which does that like the way you created the `confirm` action and present the user a button or some UI element to trigger that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question then just add in the `CasesController`:

```
def confirm
  Case.where(id: params[:id]).update!(confirmed_at: Time.now)
  # add here whatever you want to return to the caller
end
```

And then you can access this by making a **POST** request at `.../cases/:id/confirm`

Comment: Is this how I can make a right POST request?

`<td><%= link_to 'Confirm', post_confirm_path(post), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>`

Comment: use in your console `rails routes` comand. This will give you a list with all the available routes (and paths). And check there the correct path for `confirm`

Comment: I have another question to this topic: 

Is it possible to show the user, which case is already confirmed? Maybe with a symbol (e.g. check) or something like that?